# lxQt and Lubuntu session options missing from login screen, after cloning user. How do get it back?

Tags: ubuntu, users, login, lubuntu, lxqt

I found a [script in this community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204970/clone-linux-user-copy-user-based-on-another-one) that is supposed to clone users and it works, indeed.

Although, after making logoff, I'm left with only the option of making login with Openbox (which has a loop bug).

I have no idea what to do, besides reinstalling OS.

[image: login session dropdown showing only Openbox as an option]

Comment: I'm left to answer questions, using my phone. So, please, don't ask me to copy paste long logs.

Comment: I have the latest version of Lubuntu (xenial amd64).

Comment: I have installed the OS again. I'll leave the post open, so we can have an answer for Roger pepople.

Comment: In the future, you can try reinstalling lubuntu-desktop with `sudo apt install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop`. I'm not 100% sure that it'll work as I've yet to migrate to 20.04. It should do the trick.

Comment: @KGIII I will! btw, would you mind referecing my question, in the other community question? I just don't have enough points to tell people to be careful.

Comment: Which answer did you use?

Comment: @KGIII https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268405

Comment: There you go, it's done.