# debian (?) - create new user based off of an existing one (copying configs, apps, etc)

Tags: linux, debian, users, pop-os, useradd

What I want to achieve:

Use an established user to create multiple new users each of which with identical starting set ups, same applications (e.g. Slack), same configurations (e.g. conda installed and kernels defined), etc without having to go in and do the whole setup process again.

What I have tried:

**1**: I read this question
[Clone Linux user (copy user, based on another one)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204970/clone-linux-user-copy-user-based-on-another-one) and found this answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268405, which I tried and while it created the new user with correct perms and everything, it did not copy everything as I hoped it would.

**2**: I have read a bunch of other things which are either that question and answer copy-pasted on some third party blog or something along the lines of "yeah, linux doesn't support that natively" (hence the script answer above).

Is it possible to "clone" a user after setting up their account to the desired state so that new users do not have to be set up from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.  The very ancient `/etc/skel` was designed for this!  But this is less about "cloning" and more about "defining a template for new users".

When you use `adduser` to create a user, it will copy files from `/etc/skel`.  Often this is just `.bashrc` and `.profile`, but it can contain whatever you like.

If you have a user setup in a very sterile way (i.e. freshly created and set up the way you like it, with nothing personal), then you can just copy the home directory to `/etc/skel/`.    When you create a new user with `adduser`, those files will be copied to the new user's home directory.

For your specific points:

- **starting set ups**.  User-specific services are in `~/.config/systemd/user`.  Autostart desktop entries are in `~/.config/autostart`.  By copying an existing home directory to `/etc/skel` you are preserving these things.
- **applications (e.g. Slack)**.  Applications on debian are (or at least should be) installed system-wide.  If you used `sudo apt install slack`, even when it's from a third-party repository, it will have installed system-wide.  I'm not as sure about `snapd` packages.  If all you care about is new users on an existing machine, then YES, applications (e.g. slack) are all installed for that new user too.
- **same configurations (e.g. conda installed and kernels defined), etc.**. This is a little broad.

  - **Same configurations**  Yes.  That could include dark themes, browser home-pages, browser bookmarks and bash aliases amongst many more.  Those are all stored in your home directory, and so copying a home directory to `/etc/skel` will preserve that.
  - **kernels defined**, the kernel is system-wide.  All users on the same system will be running the same kernel.
  - **conda**: yes, all applications are installed system-wide (per previous point).  I see that `conda` is a package manager.  If it installs things system-wide, then all users will have it, even without doing anything to `/etc/skel`.  If it installs things to a home directory, those things need to be in `/etc/skel` to make it to a new user's home.

---

A few notes before simply copying `/home/exampleuser` to `/etc/skel`.  Be sure you are doing this with a fresh, sterile user account.  Things like ssh private and authorized_keys are also in the home directory. You probably don't want those to be duplicated.  Personal data can also exist here, so ensure you purge all of that if required.

Also, your user's permissions outside of the home directory will not be copied.  Generally, your users should only own things in their own directories.

If you have any special requirements about permissions, then it's probably a good idea to ensure those requirements are handled by groups.  For example, if you want your users to have access to some commands with `sudo`, then make sure you define these permissions in `/etc/sudoers` for a group, then ensure that the new users are part of that group on creation.

Comment: Wow, thank you for the amazing answer. The user I intend to copy is (mostly) sterile(?) I have only used it for googling things / logging into slack to reply to a message quickly. To my knowledge (as the one who set up the account) there are no ssh keys or authorized_keys yet. Essentially just installing applications and configuring them. Is there anything else I should look for before doing this? (aside from maybe creating a snapshot with timeshift in case I mess everything up)

Comment: The only thing you might backup is the existing `/etc/skel`.  If you regret a `useradd`, you can always just `userdel` and `rm -rf /home/thatNewUser`

Comment: I tried this but I found that it doesn't work perfectly? For example Firefox developer edition needs to be downloaded and moved to `/opt` and that doesn't isn't accessible to new users, additionally conda plugins are missed even though they are a part of `.conda/plugins` which I moved to skel. So I don't know what is going on

Comment: If you installed Firefox developer edition, you should check what permissions are on the binaries in that installation, and who owns it.   If you ever did a `chown -R mainuser /opt/firefox-dev-edition`, and permissions are `700` instead of `755` then `mainuser` will be the only one who can ever run the binary.  I can't speak as to how you configure your machine, but typically software deployed with a package manager is owned by `root` and has `755` permissions.  This lets anyone on the machine run it.  Sounds like this isn't the case for this installation.  I don't know anything about `conda`.

Comment: Oh:  idea about the firefox thing:  I assume you can run it via its full path (`/opt/firefox/firefox`).  Without the full path, I'm guessing you have `command not found`. Users won't be able to run software in `/opt` from any working directory unless `/opt/firefox` is in `$PATH`.  I bet your main user has `PATH=$PATH:/opt/firefox` in `.bashrc` or `.profile` but you didn't replace the original files in `/etc/skel`.

Comment: Ill triple check, but I am pretty sure I copied over the .bashrc because the Conda install script modifies `.bashrc` resulting in a path injection using the user's actual name (e.g. username) instead of $USER and so when I tried making a new user I noticed .bashrc needed to be edited and the default shell was no long zsh.

Comment: Still a bit buggy, I updated the Conda paths to have `$USER` in them, but when running `which conda` for a new user I get `/home/templateuser/anaconda/bin/` so not sure what happened. Also it is on the path, and not sure where or how that is added... or how to properly remove / replace it